# Liferay portlet deployment IVY issue

Tags: ant, liferay

After environment variable setup for ANT Home and Liferay SDK property file settings portlet creation is sucessful but getting IVY settings issue when starting deployment. I am using command line for creation and deployment of portlet.

Check below for more details:

[image]

Comment: It seems ivy resolve is unable to download relevant files. Please suggest.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/65469913

Comment: What is the output of `ant -verbose deploy`? You can edit your question with the output.